# How to fill a form input field using its ID rather than the form name with mechanize?

Tags: python, forms, mechanize, mechanize-python

I am trying to automate geocoding with python. There is a [simple website that does this](https://www.latlong.net/convert-address-to-lat-long.html), but I don't want my user to manually visit the website. I want to automatically take his adress and convert it to latitude longitude using the website. I'd like to use the mechanize library to fill a form in python. I know there are several other questions asking how to do the same thing, but I have reviewed each one of those.
They select the form using its name, or maybe a number, fill in the fields by id, and then submit the form. But submitting the form the traditional way, `br.submit()`, wouldn't work in my case because there's no `<input type='submit'>` in the form located at the website I want to fill out, https://www.latlong.net/convert-address-to-lat-long.html. Instead, the 'find' button needs to be pressed.
If you're not understanding my question, here it is simply: How can I fill this unconventional type of form such as the one on the website I mentioned? What would the code look like for such a task?

Again: https://www.latlong.net/convert-address-to-lat-long.html

Comment: If you think my question needs to be more focused, please ask me anything you need to in the comments instead of closing my question. I'm open to any kind of solution.